# Youtube google popup - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

[The popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLbmo.png)

Trying to automate a YouTube search as I'm learning python automation, however I've come across a problem. I can't figure out how to automate clicking the "I agree" on the popup, hoping someone can send a solution

Comment: //span[text()='I agree'] If you can find this tag on developers tools just click on the /parent:button tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element using xpath and click on it with the click() method: https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/

Comment: I tried 
Iagree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span')
Iagree.click()

but it still doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Are you sure that's the right xpath? You might want to double check this way: Right-click the "I agree" button and click Inspect. In the DevTools window that comes up, right-click the highlighted line, and click Copy > Copy XPath.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that it is the right xpath and nothing is happening, I was just getting an error in the terminal saying it can't be found

Comment: You might want to edit your post and add your code.

Comment: thank you will do that next time, sorted it out how to change frames to the popups iframe first then do that :)

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the iframe popup

driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")
//("iframe" for this specific example, otherwise put id of the iframe there)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span').click()

To switch back to main frame

driver.switch_to.default_content()

Answer (score 0):

```
            browser.switch_to_default_content()
            browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0])
            browser.implicitly_wait(1)
            browser.find_element_by_id('introAgreeButton').click()
            browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

I'm using 'browser' instead of 'driver' here.